# SVN merge from trunk to branch after trunk directory name has been changed

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-merge

I have a situation where I branched off trunk and after a number of days of development work in my branch, someone else changed the name of the project directory in trunk. Something like this:
    from /Project/Directory/trunk/old_dir_name
    to   /Project/Directory/trunk/new_dir_name

This has caused me a rash of problems (of course).

Looking at the log entry from when he did this, all it shows is:
    Action   Path                                   Copy from path                         Revision
    Deleted  /Project/Directory/trunk/old_dir_name
    Added    /Project/Directory/trunk/new_dir_name  /Project/Directory/trunk/old_dir_name  12345

When I tried a test merge of trunk into my branch so I'd have the latest updates, I got a Conflicted error on one file.  If I try a test merge for the latest revision of just that file I get: Error Repository moved permanently to '.../!svn/bc/13649/Project/Directory/old_dir_name/trunk'.

How do I fix this so I can keep my branch up to date as needed?

(If it matters we use the TortoiseSVN front-end).

Comment: this `/Project/Directory/trunk/old_dir_name` and `.../!svn/bc/13649/Project/Directory/old_dir_name/trunk` is a little bit incoherent. Could you clarify it?

Answer (score 0):

This is well known svn bug since 2002 - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187454/subversion-not-merging-changes-into-renamed-files).

For example if you rename file/directory(or file under it) in a branch, and the file/directory(or file under it) changed on trunk you'll have problem to merge branch to trunk.

Why this happens? It's simple - svn rename is implemented as remove of file (a) and adding it with new name (a'). So (a') on branch in my example and (a) are not inherited from the same file. Hovewer, svn tries to minimize the problem and adds to (a') tag information about (a), so if you do svn log on (a') you see rename action, as well changes of (a) too.