# Merging branches on subversion

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, repository, tortoisesvn

Could someone explain to me the process behind branching and merging? I don't know if I am doing something wrong but my merges are going very wrong. Here is my scenario:

My repository is as follows:

```
/repo
    |- branches
    |- tags
    |- trunk
        |- readme.txt         //readme stores v1.0
```

Now I need to make 2 branches; 1 for new changes and 2 for bug fixes and they are as follows:

```
/repo
    |- branches
        |- dev
            |- readme1.txt    //readme renamed to readme1 and stores v1.0
            |- readme2.txt    //this file is empty
        |- bugfix
            |- readme.txt     //readme stores v2.0
    |- tags
    |- trunk
        |- readme.txt         //readme stores v1.0
```

Details are:

- both "dev" and "bugfix" are direct branches to trunk created at the same revision
- 1 person made a change to bugfix (see diagram top)
- another person renamed readme.txt, made some modification and create a new file.

So when all changes are to be merged to the trunk it should be as follows:

```
/repo
    |- branches
    |- tags
    |- trunk
        |- readme1.txt         //readme stores v2.0
        |- readme2.txt         //this file is empty
```

To achieve this result, how should i proceed to merge my files?
I did try:

1. merging "dev" and "bugfix" which is not working because my files are being overwritten instead of being merged
2. merging "bugfix" to "trunk" followed by merging "dev" to "trunk" which is also not working as my files are still being overwritten instead of being merged

I am using Tortoise SVN connecting to an Apache Subversion repository. I really tired of trying to merge and god knows how many times i tried from all the folders that i checkout. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you use another SCM for merging? It will be the easiest way

Answer (score 0):

Here is a discussion on the bug for svn move tracking: [Subversion not merging changes into renamed files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/187454/subversion-not-merging-changes-into-renamed-files)

Comment: This section of the svnbook (from 1.7) mentions the issue you ran in to: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.advanced.html#svn.branchmerge.advanced.moves

Comment: Here is the changelog for Subversion 1.8 where it treats svn moves as a 'first-class operation': https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#moves

Comment: "First class" still will produce tree-conflict on merging Bugfix into trunk with pre-merged Dev (even 1.8+ can't handle renames+modified source)

Comment: Thanks for confirming. I removed my incorrect answer to not add to the confusion around the issue.